# Algorithm to convert algebraic chess notations to a board layout or FEN notation

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, chess

I am looking for an algorithm I can use to convert the algebraic chess notations to a matrix format or FEN notation that can be programmed in C#?

Sample algebraic notation ([info](https://www.chess.com/article/view/chess-notation#algebraic-notation)) input

```
1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 d5 4. cxd5 Nxd5 5. e4 Nxc3 6. bxc3 Bg7 7. Be3 c5 8. Rc1 O-O 9. Qd2 e5 10. d5 Qd6 11. f3 f5 12. Qc2 Nd7 13. Nh3 f4 14. Bd2 Nb6 15. Nf2 c4 16. Be2 Bd7 17. O-O Qc7 18. Rb1 Nc8 19. a4 Rf6 20. Rb4 Nd6 21. Rfb1 g5 22. Qa2 Rc8 23. a5 h5 24. h3 Rg6 25. Kf1 Bf6 26. Bd1 Bd8 27. Ra1 Rb8 28. Be1 b5 29. axb6 axb6 30. Qb1 Qb7 31. Rb2 b5 32. Rba2 Bb6 33. Ra6 Kf7 34. R1a2 Rgg8 35. Qa1 Qc7 36. Be2 Bc8 37. Ra8 Rxa8 38. Rxa8 Qc5 39. Qa3 Bd7 40. Qxc5 Bxc5 41. Ra6 Ke7 42. Nd1 Rb8 43. Bf2 Bxf2 44. Kxf2 g4 45. h4 b4 46. cxb4 Rxb4 47. Ke1 g3 48. Ra8 Bc8 49. Kd2 Rb6 50. Kc2 Rb7 51. Nb2 Rc7 52. Ra4 Bd7 53. Rb4 Ra7 54. Nxc4 Nxc4 55. Bxc4 Ra1 56. Rb6 Rg1 57. Rh6 Rxg2+ 58. Kc3 Rf2 59. d6+ Kf8 60. Rg6 Rxf3+ 61. Kb4
```

output should be
FEN

```
5k2/3b4/3P2R1/4p2p/1KB1Pp1P/5rp1/8/8 b - - 1 61
```

Or

```
--  --  --  --  --  bK  --  --
--  --  --  bB  --  --  --  --
--  --  --  wp  --  --  wR  --
--  --  --  --  bp  --  --  bp
--  wK  wB  --  wp  bp  --  wp
--  --  --  --  --  bR  bp  --
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
```

At the moment I can convert FEN to above board notation, but algebraic notation is far more challenging. I am only after final board structure, I don't care about move order.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you want to convert the matrix above to FEN or Algebraic Notation? If that's the case, then it's impossible to convert the matrix to Algebraic.

Comment: You might want to explain (or give a link that explains) what _algebraic chess notation_ is.  Generally, when I think _mapping_, I think `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, but I don't know enough about the problem domain to help here (I don't think)

Comment: thanks for the response, @Hayden, I am looking to convert other direction (Algebraic  to FEN). I have also added more info about notations.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Algebraic notation is used to describe moves in a game, while FEN is used to describe a position in the game.  The two do not server the same function.

Comment: @kw1jybo, once you execute the move order on  Algebraic notation, it will place the pieces on the board in a certain way (which can be described with FEN). That is what I am looking for, all piece positions on the board after executing  Algebraic notation.
example 
https://www.dcode.fr/chess-notation

Comment: What exactly is challenging about algebraic notation? BTW, you _should care about the move order, otherwise you can't reliable determine the castling rights, and the possibility of en passant. So, just play the moves.

Comment: There is no shortcut.  You have to program an engine that can list possible moves, and match which possible move matches the one you do next, then can figure out what happened, and output the new board state.  For example your Nf6 could be written as Nf6, Ngf6, N8f6 or Nf8f6. (A game which requires the last would be seriously weird.) It needs to know the full rules of chess to do that.

Comment: thanks for the responses. I was able to find a solution using an existing lib. https://github.com/NoNamePro0/Chess.Core